# A guy hires man to commit suicide-by-assassin, but killer fails, kills other people accidentally?

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

Movie starts with a (I assume British) guy who wants to commit suicide but he does not succeed. He meets a local guy who wants to earn some money and tells him that he will kill the suicidal man.

But he is not a real killer, every time he tries, he fails. But other people die (for example some older lady is hit by rock by mistake, some cops eat the poisoned cake, etc).

I think it's Czech (not sure about that) comedy/drama/crime from around 1990-2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're after [Shut Up and Shoot Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0406219/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl):

> Long-suffering Czech Pavel Zeman works six jobs, so his ungrateful
>   wife Liba can buy designer shoes and clothes. Colin Frampton is an
>   Englishman who never stops worrying, not even on holiday in Prague.
>   When Colin's wife is accidentally squashed by a statue, he decides
>   that he can't face life without her. So Colin bribes Pavel to help him
>   die. An unlikely friendship develops as Pavel's plans for Colin's
>   death spin out of control, attracting the violent interest of local
>   gangster Karel Karlovic.

Comment: Yes, exactly this one. I was trying to find it for more than one hours but sadly google is not best tool to find "suicide" movies. Thank you

Comment: No problem. I happened to see it in a cinema once, great black comedy.